# C# and google speak

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech, arabic

I'm currently working on a c# project and want the user to type a sentence and then speak this sentence using google text to speech engine. I can't use C# speech synthesizer because it only support English language and I want it in Arabic. does anyone know how to invoke google tts?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code that does it:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows)");
    client.DownloadFile("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ar&q=مرحبا العالم", "HelloWorld.wav");
}
```

It will save a `HelloWorld.wav` file that contains the phrase behind the `q` parameter - sorry if it doesn't really mean something in arabic :-)